# Azure storage queues: dequeue strategy other than FIFO

Tags: azure, queue, storage

Has anybody thought about implementing strategies for Azure storage queues that would allow dequeuing messages in an arbitrary order (other than first-in, first-out). For examples, some people might be interested in LIFO, some people might want to dequeue "important" messages ahead of less important ones, etc.

Personally, I am interested in implementing a strategy that would allow messages in a multi-tenant system to be dequeued in a way that ensures large number of messages related to a particular tenant will not cause messages for other tenants to be delayed.

I am also interested in other queuing systems that may have implemented similar strategies.
Are there other queuing systems that allow this kind of

Comment: Did you finally found a solution suiting this case ? I have the same need in a shared environment.

Comment: I never found a solution that completely satisfied me. The best I came up with was to create an arbitrary number of queues, say 4 for example, and assign each tenant to one of these queues. In the case where one tenant generates a very large number of messages, only 1/4 of the tenants will be impacted. This is obviously not a perfect solution, but it's better than causing all tenants to be impacted if you have only a single queue.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is referred to as a **Priority Queue Pattern** which you can read more about [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589794.aspx).

There are a couple of strategies for achieving this. One is to use different queues for the higher priority messages. Or in your case, a queue for each customer.

Another approach, and is one I would prefer for your scenario, is to use the ServiceBus Topics and Subscriptions (pub/sub basically).

Both of these are discussed in more detail in the link provided above.

Comment: Very interesting article. Thanks for linking. However, this pattern it seems more suited to scenarios where the "levels" or "priorities" are known in advance (the article uses "high" and low" priorities as examples). What about scenarios where the priorities are not known, and in fact vary over time?

Answer (score 0):

The priority queue pattern is the way to go. Use different queues for different message priorities. You can also assign appropriate numbers of workers to each queue to drain at an appropriate rate.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Any recommendation for scenarios where priorities are not known ahead of time and can vary over time. I am interested in a scenario where each tenant would have their own "topic" or "priority" and tenants are added regularly to the system.